# Can bounded bijective linear operator $A:X\to X$ has an inverse with norm strictly larger than $\frac{1}{||A||}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $A:X\to X$ is linear and bijective. It is known that $A^{-1}$ is bounded and
$$ \mid\mid A\mid\mid \cdot\mid\mid A^{-1} \mid\mid \ge \mid\mid AA^{-1} \mid\mid =\mid\mid \mathrm{id} \mid\mid =1,$$
i.e. $\mid\mid A\mid\mid \ge \frac{1}{\mid\mid A^{-1}\mid\mid } $.

Is there any example s.t. "$>$" holds strictly, i.e. $\mid\mid A\mid\mid > \frac{1}{\mid\mid A^{-1}\mid\mid } $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $X=\mathbb C^2$ with the Euclidean norm and take a diagonal
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} a&0\\0&b\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $a>b>0$, then it is easy to check that $\|A\|=a$ and $\|A^{-1}\|=\frac1b$. So you can prescribe $\|A\|=a$ and still make $\|A^{-1}\|$ as large as you want.

Concretely, take
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1/n\end{bmatrix} 
$$
for a positive integer $n$.
Then $\|A\|=1$ and $\|A^{-1}\|=n$.

Comment: Thank you! This example is much more concise than what I expected.